# Laravel 5.6 - Authenticate without password, using email address only

Tags: laravel-5.6

I would like to authenticate users providing their email address only, using Laravel 5.6.

Is there a way to achieve that with the Auth::login()?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
Auth::login($user);
```

The given User object must be an implementation of the  Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract. Of course, the App\User model included with Laravel already implements this interface:

official doc [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods)